# How to put a case statement into {}

Tags: swift, cocoa, closures

Okay So I am working on a project and trying to make it neat and visibly understandable where everything is is difficult. To my knowledge Xcode doesn't have an Indent Guide, but something is does have is the ability to collapse the code inside `{}` like this:

[image: Collapsed Bracket]

This can work for any `{}`. I want to make my code easier to read, so I am trying to use this effect inside of a case, so it is easier to see all of the cases at once, I did this:

```
switch transition {

case .SlideOutside:
    { /* Error */
        print("Pretend that there is hundreds of lines of code here.")
    }
    break
default: //The Default will be Fade
    break
}
```

But I get the error

> Braced block of statements is an unused closure

On line 4 with the opening bracket. I don't know how to fix this, could somebody please help.

Comment: You don't need `break` at the end of cases in Swift.  That is the default behavior (unlike in C).  The `break` you have in default: needs to stay if you have no other code there.

Comment: @vacawma Thank you I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence

> and trying to make it neat and visibly understandable

and this one

> Pretend that there is hundreds of lines of code here.

are not very compatible :)

### Solution 1

Writing

```
{
    /* Error */
    print("Pretend that there is hundreds of lines of code here.")
}
```

you created a closure but you did not run it. To execute the block you need to add `()` like shown below

```
{
    /* Error */
    print("Pretend that there is hundreds of lines of code here.")
}()
```

### Solution 2

If you really are putting hundreds of lines inside a switch case I think you should better struct you code.

The first thing to do is moving all that code inside a function in order to put only the invocation of the function inside the Switch Case.

```
switch transition {
case .SlideOutside: slideOutInside()
default: fade()
}
```

Next you should look at that function with hundreds of line and manage ti split it into subfunctions (and so on).

Comment: :P They don't do they. Thank You.